# Yates Shuffle Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a so called 'Yates Shuffle' in Excel VBA, but I got stuck.

**How it works:**
When you have a set of columns (I'm working with 25 columns) you need to take the first column all the way on the left and swap it with a random column on the right of the column you took. Once you did that, you pin the column and you go to the column on the right (the second column). Swap it with a random column on the right, and so on until you've swapped all the columns.

**What I have:**
So far I have made the columns and I have the randomizer ready, but I can't figure out how to attach the randomizer to the columns (so that the randomizer will randomize the columns instead of getting a random number of the column). Swapping the columns is the biggest issue.

**My code:**

```
Sub Fischer()

Dim blok As Range

Set blok = Range("A1:Y25")

blok.Interior.Color = vbWhite

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 25

    Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(i, i)).Interior.Color = vbgrey

Next

'Dim keuzeruimte As Range

'Set keuzeruimte = Range(Cells(1, i + 1), Cells(i + 1, i + 1))

Dim j As Integer

Dim Col2 As Range

Dim Col1 As Range

Dim Temp As Range

For i = 1 To 24

    Set Col1 = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(i, i))

    j = Int(25 - (i + 1)) * Rnd + (i + 1)

    MsgBox (j)

    Set Col2 = Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(j, j))

    Set Temp = Col1

    Col1 = Col2

    Col2 = Temp

   Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing exactly what you've told it to do. But that's slightly different than what you described. If you want to swap the contents of the entire column of data, then you need a small adjustment. (It will make it more obvious what your code is doing if you fill the cells with values, in addition to changing the format color.)

You have to locate your swap column (`Temp`) in a specific location to use it the way you want. So to swap only values, your loop should read:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fischer()
    Dim blok As Range
    Set blok = Range("A1:Y25")
    blok.Interior.Color = vbWhite

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 25
        Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(i, i)).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Next

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Col2 As Range
    Dim Col1 As Range
    Dim Temp As Range
    Set Temp = Range(Cells(1, 27), Cells(25, 27))

    For i = 1 To 24
        Set Col1 = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(25, i))
        j = Int(25 - (i + 1)) * Rnd + (i + 1)
        Debug.Print j
        Set Col2 = Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(25, j))
        Temp.Value = Col1.Value
        Col1.Value = Col2.Value
        Col2.Value = Temp.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

If swapping the formats is what you really want, then you still have to anchor your `Temp` column somewhere else, but it's now a copy-pasta method:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fischer2()
    Dim blok As Range
    Set blok = Range("A1:Y25")
    blok.Interior.Color = vbWhite

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 25
        Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(i, i)).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Next

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Col2 As Range
    Dim Col1 As Range
    Dim Temp As Range
    Set Temp = Range(Cells(1, 27), Cells(25, 27))

    For i = 1 To 24
        Set Col1 = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(25, i))
        j = Int(25 - (i + 1)) * Rnd + (i + 1)
        Debug.Print j
        Set Col2 = Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(25, j))
        Col1.Copy
        Temp.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
        Col2.Copy
        Col1.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
        Temp.Copy
        Col2.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    Next
End Sub
```